# Changing a ruby loop variable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, variables, sorting, loops

Within my controller I have two ways of sorting my database of images:

```
def index
   @picslist = Pic.order("created_at DESC")

   @picslist2 = Pic.order("price DESC")
end
```

Within my view I lay them out:

```
<% @picslist.each do |pic| %>
    PICS IN HERE
<% end %>
```

I want to alter the `@picslist` variable to `@picslist2` with a JavaScript click event, something like so:

```
$("#sortbyprice").click(function(event) {

    //replace @picslist with @picslist2

});
```

Is that the right way of doing it? Either way I'd be grateful if you could recommend a graceful way of doing this!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: when you use javascript, you change html. Ruby code has already been interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help... I actually found the best way to do it was by essentially just sorting the results, as detailed [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 0):

making two objects @picslist and @picslist2 is not good idea.
Pass the sort_by params when javascript event occured.

```
def index
   @picslist = Pic.order("#{params[:sort_by]} DESC")  
end
```

where params[:sort_by] will be "created_at" or "price"

Something like that and use ajax or form submit to update the page.

Comment: Many thanks... I actually found I was doing it totally wrong, and just needed to add sort params. Have answered below.

Comment: also, using `"#{params[:sort_by]} DESC"` might not be a good idea, due to sql injection, you could use a helper method to eliminate that